# .NET ConcurrentStack, missing exp backoff in push operation

Tags: .net, algorithm, concurrency, lock-free

I found, that the .NET ConcurrentStack implementation uses exponential backoff after the first failed CAS operation in the Pop method, but not in the Push method.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentStack.cs
(pushCore, popCore methods)

I thought, that after a failed CAS operation it's better not to try again immediately because the next attempt will likely fail again in high load. That's (not only) why exponential backoff is used in such lock-free algorithms.

Can someone explain me, why this can be left out in the Push method but not in the Pop method?

Comment: Those spin waits seem to be of dubious value.  Total throughput appears to be improved if you just get rid of them.

Comment: I haven't read it all, but the only popCore I saw there, with what looks like a back-off mechanism, can pop multiple nodes. I believe the back-off is targeting a scenario where you pop more than one. If you're trying to pop 10 nodes, there's no point in immediate retry.